# Use Display Name attribute for column header in exported Excel data

Tags: c#, .net, excel, attributes, epplus

I am trying to use a DisplayName attribute to modify the column headers in data exported to an Excel file. I want "My Name" but get "MyName". The data is data returned from a query, converted to a `List`, then to a `DataTable`, then exported to Excel.
What else can I try?

There is [some discussion here](https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/428843) saying that functionality for this was being added.

Using .NET Framework 4

```
    public class MyExcelViewModel
    {
            private string myName;
            //[System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Mine Name")] // no effect
            //[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations("My Name")] // doesn't compile
            //[System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute("My Name")] // no effect
            [Display(Name = "My Name")] // no effect
            public string MyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyController : Controller
        // initialize exportList
        IList<MyExcelViewModel> exportList = new List<MyExcelViewModel>(fromQueryList.Count);
        foreach (var value in fromQueryList)
        {
            exportList.Add(new MyExcelViewModel());
        }

        DataTable dataTable = ConvertListToDataTable(exportList); // convert to DataTable
        Export_EPPlus(dataTable); // export

        private void Export_EPPlus(DataTable dataTable)
        {
                 using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
                 {
                     ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(" Results");

                     // Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1.
                     worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

                     worksheet.View.FreezePanes(2, 1); // freeze first row & column
                     worksheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;

                     worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns(); // autofit column width

                     for (int rowNumber = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row; rowNumber <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
                     {
                         int rowIndex = rowNumber % 2; // even => 0, odd => 1
                         ExcelRow excelRow = worksheet.Row(rowNumber);
                         ExcelFill excelFillRow = excelRow.Style.Fill;
                         excelFillRow.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                         switch (rowIndex)
                         {
                             case 0:
                                 excelFillRow.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                                 break;
                             case 1:
                                 excelFillRow.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
                                 break;
                         }
                     }

                     try
                     {
                         // Write to client
                         Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename="Results-EPPlus.xlsx");
                         Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());

                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                         System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("MyController.Export_EPPlus(): exception: " + ex);
                     }
                 }
             }

        public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return table;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DisplayName` attribute thing only works in 4.0, not with 3.1 unfortunately. The only way to do it in version 3.1 is to manually set the `Caption` of each `DataColumn` in the `DataTable` record, as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.caption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I wrote a blog post on that and other new 4.0 features in practice that can be found [here](http://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/easy_excel_interaction_pt7).

As proof, here is the relevant code from EPPlus 3.1 that prints the column headers in the `LoadFromDataTable` method:

```
if (PrintHeaders)
{
  foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in (InternalDataCollectionBase) Table.Columns)
    this._worksheet.Cell(row, num++).Value = (object) dataColumn.Caption;
  ++row;
  num = this._fromCol;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking here:  https://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/118053   I see version 4.0.1 listed as Stable. So ... not so beta?

Comment: Well, I'll be darned. They released it and I didn't notice. Thanks for that.